# How to uri-encode unicode strings in Racket

Tags: string, unicode, encoding, uri, racket

the following code gives me an error:

`(uri-encode "Kidô senkan Nadeshiko")`

which is,

```
vector-ref: index is out of range
  index: 244
  valid range: [0, 127]
  vector: '#("%00" "%01" "%02" "%03" "%04" "%05" "%06" "%07" "%08" "%09" "%0A" "%0B" "%0C" "%0D" "%0E" "%0F" "%10" "%11" "%12" "%13" "%...
  context...:
   /usr/lib/racket/collects/net/uri-codec.rkt:197:6: for-loop
   /usr/lib/racket/collects/net/uri-codec.rkt:195:0: encode
   /usr/lib/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7
```

I guess `uri-encode` and `uri-decode` only support ASCII which I can infer from the source of some tests, [here](http://code.google.com/p/racket/source/browse/collects/tests/net/uri-codec.rkt?spec=svnc2280ed8dc5d1f8d4fc690108ce5e9e9ae53d117&r=c2280ed8dc5d1f8d4fc690108ce5e9e9ae53d117)

So my question is, is there a library on github or elsewhere that will uri encode unicode strings properly? Or do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might have something to do with the way you're running the program, or the version of Racket in use. I tested this in Racket 5.2.1 and it works for me:

```
#lang racket
(require net/uri-codec)

(uri-encode "Kidô senkan Nadeshiko")
=> "Kid%C3%B4%20senkan%20Nadeshiko"
```

Comment: Okay, yes, it works for me under Racket 5.3.4, but this error happens under 5.3.4.10, so I'm guessing it's a bug?

Comment: @Wes so it seems, better fill a bug report ;)